# Wrong format with fixing htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine onRewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/jedpanel\.com\/" [R=301,L]
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModulemod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine OnRewriteBase 
/RewriteRule^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-dRewriteRule . /index.php [L]</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

but I have a problem. When I saved it something went wrong and the format changed. I tried to fix it but this is what I got. Can anyone please fix it because the webpage gives `500 Internal Server error`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it now:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xinlongboard\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xinlongboard\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/jedpanel\.com\/" [R=301,L]

# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I'm not quite sure what you were doing to mess up the format as you did. Next time only edit it via your hosting, will prevent this mess.

Comment: I was tryng to enable gzip compression but it didn't work don't know why :/

Comment: What were you using to edit the file? To change the format as you did upon saving can only mean you were using an unusual editor of some type.

Comment: I used Notepad.

Comment: Strange.. notepad would not change your formatting.

Comment: Yes I just added some code after the last line and saved the file, nothing else.Thanks for your help I would give you some points but I don't have reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself.
Here is the code if someone is interested:

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xinlongboard\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xinlongboard\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/jedpanel\.com\/" [R=301,L]
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```